# Visual database design tool for MySQL 4.*

Tags: windows, database, mysql

I am looking for a visual database design tool that:

- integrates SQL development
- can browse databases and tables graphically
- supports the connection method TCP/IP over SSH (like MySQL Workbench)
- supports MySQL 4.* ([unlike](http://hordine.com/2012/06/misleading-instructions-from-mysqlworkbench-for-mysql-server-version-is-older-than-5-0-which-is-not-supported/) MySQL Workbench)
- works on Windows 8

If possible:

- is still maintained (i.e. not some old, buggy, feature-poor versions)
- free

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) for this, I've used it in a few projects involving MySQL and it works great:

- Built-in SQL code editor and graphical browser for almost every object in the server.
- Not completely sure about MySQL 4X (not used it since a long time ago, and don't have a handy server to try), most likely latest version can use it, but even then, older version will work for sure.
- Also supports MSSQL (to some extent) and is developing experimental PostgreSQL support, within the same environment.
- Can connect though TCP/IP, named pipes or SSH tunnels (requires plink.exe from [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for this).
- Still actively developed.
- Open source.

[image: Graphical database editor]
[image: SQL code editor]
[image: SSH tunnel connection]