# Software/tool to design database diagrams for MSSQL

Tags: open-source, sql-server

I am looking for a free software/tool to design database diagrams for MSSQL. There are some online tools which I think great but not free

- https://sqldbm.com
- https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/

The below thread answers my question but its for MySqL:

[Visual database design tool for MySQL 4.*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13203/visual-database-design-tool-for-mysql-4)

Comment: In the answer from 2014 in the from you cited answer I read: "Also supports MSSQL (to some extent) and is developing experimental PostgreSQL support, within the same environment." Which problems do you have with the recommended package?

Comment: @albert I have not tried it. Need to check